# Command to clear SQL PLUS prompt

Tags: oracle, command-prompt, sqlplus

What is the command to clear **SQL PLUS** prompt? **'Clear'** or **'Cls'** won't work for me!

Comment: Yeah it seems, Sql Plus works with 'clear scr'. Thanks.

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve012.htm#SQPUG033

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `clear screen` as documented in the manual:

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve012.htm#SQPUG033